Telling time after 12 AM
The other day I was watching a video on Youtube and the guy in that video was complaining about his neighbor. When his neighbor, a frail old lady, came to his house at 01:30 in the morning and complained about something, he got pissed. He was shocked that she came at 01:30 in the morning. That phrase really caught my attention.
Do native speakers use the expression "in the morning" after 12 AM even though it`s actually pitch dark?

Since 'a.m.' means 'before noon', midnight could be seen as both 12 a.m. and 12 p.m.! (sorry - a pet peeve of mine.)

@KateBunting It's definitely a confusing point, but pretty sure there's an "official" answer that midnight is 12am and noon is 12pm. I guess the idea being that, if we're measuring a "time line," a 1-dimensional string of numbers, then "the meridian" is a point, 0-dimensional. At 12:00:01 we're already past it.

Related: Why 11 am + 1 hour == 12:00 pm?

People never, or very rarely say '01:30', ('oh-one-colon-thirty'), especially followed by 'in the morning'. The morning starts at midnight at lasts until noon, so 'one-thirty in the morning' is a normal saying. Even in lands where the 24-hour or 'military' time formal is in widespread or official use, people often stick to the 12-hour format for events in their home lives.

Yes, this is common wording. Here are some idiomatic phrases that a native speaker might use to describe something happening any time after midnight and before sunrise/standard wakeup time:

A: I can't believe my son, he was out until all hours last night. He
came home at two in the morning! Can you believe it? What's a parent supposed to do?
B: When my daughter was a teenager, we had a strict curfew. She had to be home by 10 pm and in bed by 11. She wouldn't have dreamed of coming home at 2 am.
A: God! I wish my son was responsible like that. Even when he is home he's up in the middle of the night.

As a conjecture, Americans especially might use in the morning phrasing to distinguish 2 am from 2 pm, since the US exclusively uses a 12-hour clock. So often when you are verbally talking about time, you'll add "In the afternoon" or "In the morning" or "At night" etc. after the number to clarify whether you mean AM or PM. These phrases are used in spoken English interchangeably with "AM" and "PM."

Oddly enough, times in the PM might variously be "in the afternoon," "in the evening," or "at night" depending on the specific time, but for AM it's always "in the morning."

@YonKuma - except that early AM hours are often considered "in the middle of the night"

@DJ. I'm referring exclusively to these used with the hour in a phrase, eg "two in the morning" or "one in the morning". I don't think I've ever heard anyone say "one in the middle of the night".

@YonKuma Oh ok sorry

It sounds unusual to say "in the morning" even if it is technically true, when it is actually the middle of the night.

@Beqa  No, it sounds unusual if you translate it word by word into your language.  In English it sounds normal.  morning starts at 12am and continues until 12pm.  1am is both "in the middle of the night" and "1 in the morning"

@JamesK We say "in the morning" when the Sun rises; from that point to12 o`clock probably. When it is 01:30, we say in the middle of the night because it is actually night.

By "We" do you mean "in my language", because in your language you don't say "morning" you say " صَبَاح" or "上午" or "בֹּקֶר / בוקר " or "დილა" or "mattino". All of these are glosses of "Morning" in other languages, and in some languages it would sound unusual but in English it doesn't. What I mean is "your native language isn't English" so don't expect the same idioms in English as in your native language.

@JamesK It is not unusual and weird only to my ears as an ESL learner but it is indeed illogical to say "it is 01:30 in the morning" when these word are being uttered in the middle of the night.

No.  You mean "if I translate to Georgian it is weird, because the Georgian word დილა cannot be used like this." But English isn't Georgian......  It is not weird  In English because in English the word "morning includes the time after 12am.    There is nothing illogical about this.  In Japanese, green vegetables are "blue" because the word "aoi" (translated as blue) includes the dark green colour of vegetables.  Nothing about "logic", just the fact that the Japanese word doesn't mean exactly the same as the English one.

@Beqa I think you're right, I think it's also a little weird and funny, since by all other measures, "morning" is usually defined as a time starting when the sun rises, and this is definitely before that. But just about every language is full of little funny things ¯_(ツ)_/¯

@JamesK I have a question to you.  When you use this expression "in the middle of the night", what time do you have in mind?

roughly between about 11pm and 3am.  It's often a piece of hyperbole. A parent might say "Why aren't you asleep, it's the middle of the night" to a child who is awake beyond their bedtime.  But you don't say "It's 1 o'clock in the middle of the night"  You say "It's one o'clock in the morning" because that's the idiomatic expression in English
